# print only once in "if loop" inside a "while loop"

Tags: c, linux, if-statement, while-loop

In linux ubuntu 14.04, I am trying to count the lines of input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*count lines in input*/

main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            nl = nl + 1;
        printf("input lines are %d\n", nl);
    }
}
```

The output is however:

```
   asdsadsa
input lines are 0
input lines are 0
input lines are 0
input lines are 0
input lines are 0
input lines are 0
input lines are 0
input lines are 0
input lines are 1
asdasd
input lines are 1
input lines are 1
input lines are 1
input lines are 1
input lines are 1
input lines are 1
input lines are 2
```

Comment: Format your code properly. Check the preview pane before submitting, and read the "How to format" box to the right while you are editing

Comment: The output looks correct for your input  and code , you should also explain what you expected to see and how what you actually saw differs

Comment: `if` is not a looping/iteration statement. And using non-prototype declarators is deprecated.

Comment: Indentation means nothing to the C compiler.  Braces do. Your `printf` statement is not within the scope of your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some braces.

```
if (c == '\n') {
    nl = nl + 1;
    printf("input lines are %d\n", nl);
}
```

By not having them then only the nl increment is affected by the if statement and you want both.

Comment: Multiple *parentheses*.

Comment: `{` `}` are usually called *braces* . "Parentheses" only refers to round brackets `( )`.

Comment: @EOF: Actually [_braces_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.1p1).

Comment: @EOF - Thanks, for wrong reason I misthought the word.

Comment: @JamesBlack I'm apparently weird about pluralizations. Don't get me started on people who write "indexes".

Answer (score 1):

Without your expectation, I could only guess it:

You may want this (you have to use Ctrl+D to indicate the end of input):

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*count lines in input*/

int main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
            nl = nl + 1;
    }
    printf("input lines are %d\n", nl);
}
```

Or this(out print immediately after a line is inputted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*count lines in input*/

int main()
{
    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            nl = nl + 1;
            printf("input lines are %d\n", nl);
        }
    }
}
```